# How to run headless REMOTE chrome using robot framework

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

I'm trying to run chrome headless with my robot framework tests suites.
I managed to do it independtly with python using selenium as follows:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
my_driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executer=my_remote_address, desired_capabilities=options.to_capabilities)
```

The following code is what I did in robot but didn't work:

```
${options}=  Evaluate  sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()  sys, selenium.webdriver
${options.add_argument}=  Set Variable  add_argument=--headless
Create WebDriver  Chrome  chrome_options=${options}

Open Browser   http://www.google.com   chrome
```

Comment: Skip down a few answers, it's now a oneliner:
`Open Browser      http://www.yoursite.com    headlesschrome` (At least if you're here for a local solution)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To run headless you need to set the arguments and convert them to capabilities so that they can be used when using the `Remote Driver` option. This works for both the `Open Browser` as well as the `Create Webdriver` way of navigating to a URL.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Selenium2Library

Suite Teardown    Close All Browsers

*** Test Cases ***
Headless Chrome - Create Webdriver
    ${chrome_options} =     Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}   add_argument    headless
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}   add_argument    disable-gpu
    ${options}=     Call Method     ${chrome_options}    to_capabilities      

    Create Webdriver    Remote   command_executor=http://localhost:4444/wd/hub    desired_capabilities=${options}

    Go to     http://cnn.com

    Maximize Browser Window
    Capture Page Screenshot

Headless Chrome - Open Browser
    ${chrome_options} =     Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}   add_argument    headless
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}   add_argument    disable-gpu
    ${options}=     Call Method     ${chrome_options}    to_capabilities     

    Open Browser    http://cnn.com    browser=chrome    remote_url=http://localhost:4444/wd/hub     desired_capabilities=${options}

    Maximize Browser Window
    Capture Page Screenshot
```

Comment: For the second solution (`Open Browser  [...]  chrome`) the call to `to_capabilities` can be saved, when passing the options as `chrome_options=${chrome_options}`.

Comment: @A.Kootstra why do you need the `remote_url` in open browser?

Comment: When using a Selenium Grid, this is the url tot he Grid Server.

Answer (score 30):

In newer versions of SeleniumLibrary (3.1.0) and Selenium (3.8.0) you can simply set the browser to `headlesschrome` instead of `chrome`.

There's also `headlessfirefox` available.

Ex.

```
Open Browser      http://www.yoursite.com    headlesschrome
```

http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Open%20Browser

Comment: The example will open a local headless chrome. The question was about connecting to a Selenium Grid and starting a remote headless chrome instance.

Answer (score 3):

Please try the below. Run the keyword in Test setup

```
Running the tests in chrome headless
    ${chrome options} =     Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
    Call Method    ${chrome options}   add_argument    headless
    Call Method    ${chrome options}   add_argument    disable-gpu
    Create Webdriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${chrome options}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can now use aliases:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Firefox
    Open Browser    http://robotframework.org/    headlessfirefox
    Capture Page Screenshot
    [Teardown]    Close All Browsers

Chrome
    Open Browser    http://robotframework.org/     headlesschrome
    Capture Page Screenshot
    [Teardown]    Close All Browsers
```

See https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary/pull/1011

Answer (score 1):

Try out these two keywords:

```
Open Chrome
    [Arguments]    ${url}    ${lang}
    ${chrome_options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    headless
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    disable-gpu
    Create Webdriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${chrome_options}
    Go To    ${url}

Open Remote Chrome
    [Arguments]    ${url}    ${remote_url}    ${lang}
    ${chrome_options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    headless
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    disable-gpu
    Open Browser    ${url}    Chrome    remote_url=${remote_url}    desired_capabilities=${chrome_options.to_capabilities()}
```

First one will launch a local chrome, while the second one is to launch a remote chrome. If you need to be able to handle the remote vs. local into a single keyword, you can create a wrapper around these two with a boolean argument that will determine which keyword to call.

Answer (score 1):

```
${options}=  Evaluate  sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()  sys, selenium.webdriver
Call Method    ${options}    add_argument    headless
Call Method    ${options}    add_argument    disable-gpu
Create WebDriver  Chrome  chrome_options=${options}
Goto  https://www.cnn.com/
Wait Until Page Contains    Politics today
Close Browser
```