# No keyword with name 'Start Virtual Display' found

Tags: frameworks, robotframework, xvfb

I've been doing some research into headless testing with Robot Framework and I've come across Xvfb. So I installed it with:

pip install robotframework-xvfb

Then in my test case file, I've added:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Selenium2Library
Library  XvfbRobot

*** Test Cases ***
Creating a headless browser
    [Tags]  Headless
    Starting your display
    The user goes to the website
    Maximizing the window
    The user enters an incorrect email
    The user sees they have entered an incorrect email
```

My keywords are all good, no visible errors. Yet when I run the test, it returns the following:

```
Importing test library 'XvfbRobot' failed: ImportError: No module named xvfbwrapper
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/robot-framework/3.0.2_1/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/XvfbRobot/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from xvfbwrapper import Xvfb
```

Anyone come across this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you installed xvfbwrapper?

Comment: Yeah, I had already installed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [robotframework-xfvb](https://github.com/drobota/robotframework-xvfb) library requirements list it clearly states that xfvb should be manually installed. This is confirmed from the installation scripts of robotframework-xfvb and that of [xfvbwrapper](https://github.com/cgoldberg/xvfbwrapper) module, which does not install xfvb either.

Bear in mind that xfvb is not a Python module but an application that should be installed. Typically this is done by `sudo apt-get install xvfb`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. For `sudo apt-get install xvfb` , it won't work on a Mac, so I've tried `pip install xvfb` and `brew install xvfb`, but no progress there either. Do you know the command for Mac?

Comment: Can I ask why you want to use xfvb on MacOS? If it's to run Chrome in a headless mode, there is a chrome startup argument for it which is a lot easier.

Comment: Yeah I'd like to run it headless with Chrome.

Comment: This is already possible. In this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46817149/6152737) answer replace `Remote` with `Chrome` and remove the `remote_url=...` bit and you'll have a headless running Robot Test.

Comment: Good to hear. Can you mark this as the answer for you?

Comment: Sure thing, can't seem to select the comment as the answer, only your original post.