# How to parametrize Open Browser keyword in robot framework to run headless from command line?

Tags: robotframework

Open Browser        ${REMOTE_URL}       ${HEADLESS}

I want to pass the headlesschrome value to Open Browser keyword from commandline

Comment: Could you please check the following https://stackoverflow.com/a/46817149/10841478

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make the chrome headless to work, below code should work.
When you want to parametrize then forllow this doc - https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#resource-and-variable-files

Create all the variables and store it in a file and then, when calling any of the below code use the following syntax, OR, pass the respective name:value as shown below from command line to use the same in your robot code.

```
robot -v <<variable file>> *.robot

OR

robot -v name:value *.robot
```

package list

```
(rf2) C:\Users\kgurupra>pip list
Package                         Version
------------------------------- ---------
appdirs                         1.4.3
beautifulsoup4                  4.8.1
certifi                         2018.8.24
chardet                         3.0.4
colorama                        0.4.1
configparser                    4.0.2
crayons                         0.3.0
idna                            2.8
pip                             19.3.1
requests                        2.22.0
robotframework                  3.1.2
robotframework-selenium2library 3.0.0
robotframework-seleniumlibrary  4.1.0
robotframework-xvfb             1.2.2
selenium                        3.141.0
setuptools                      40.2.0
soupsieve                       1.9.5
tqdm                            4.38.0
urllib3                         1.25.7
webdriver-manager               2.3.0
webdrivermanager                0.7.4
wheel                           0.31.1
wincertstore                    0.2
xvfbwrapper                     0.2.9
```

Code

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Selenium2Library

*** Test Cases ***
Test title
    ${options}=  Evaluate  sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()  sys, selenium.webdriver
    Call Method    ${options}    add_argument    --headless
    #my_create_webdriver   googlechrome  ${options}
    create webdriver  Chrome  chrome_options=${options}
    Maximize Browser Window
    go to   https://google.com
    Maximize Browser Window
    capture page screenshot
    close browser
```

Using OpenBrowser Headless

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Selenium2Library

*** Test Cases ***
Test title
    ${options}=  Evaluate  sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()  sys, selenium.webdriver
    Call Method    ${options}    add_argument    --headless
    #my_create_webdriver   Chrome  ${options}
    Open Browser    http://google.com       Headless Chrome
#    create webdriver  Chrome  chrome_options=${options}
    Maximize Browser Window
    go to   https://google.com
    Maximize Browser Window
    capture page screenshot
    close browser
```

**OUTPUT**

```
(rf2) C:\Users\kgurupra>robot sa.robot
==============================================================================
Sa
==============================================================================
Test title                                                            ..
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:54461/devtools/browser/ff94b77f-b963-428f-835e-f5e1932a1915
Test title                                                            | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sa                                                                    | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  C:\Users\kgurupra\output.xml
Log:     C:\Users\kgurupra\log.html
Report:  C:\Users\kgurupra\report.html
```

**Better approach**

Xvfb is a headless display server for the X Window System, instead if making chrome/firefox to run headless, why not use the below method instead.

Install XvfbRobot library for Robot Framework, this is a robot library for creating virtual display which can be used for running selenium tests in headless mode.

```
pip install robotframework-xvfb
```

Example

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     This example demonstrates how to use current library
Library      Selenium2Library
Library      XvfbRobot

*** Test Cases ***
Create Headless Browser
    Start Virtual Display    1920    1080
    Open Browser   http://google.com
    Set Window Size    1920    1080
    ${title}=    Get Title
    Should Be Equal    Google    ${title}
    [Teardown]    Close Browser
```

Comment: Cool. Is there anyway I can parameterize Xvfb from the terminal? Ex:robot --variable BROWSER:headlesschrome tests.robot

Comment: You need to follow the same steps mentioned in the link. you will be able to do it, just follow the code.